# yaml css input field and jquery date field

Tags: css, yaml

I have a question about the yaml css question. I have been trying all day to get a jquery date field to display next to a yaml css field but the best i can manage is the following...[image]

I would love the date picker to be on the right of the input field rather than underneath it. For all you yaml ppl out there do you know how i can achieve this? Thanks for your help in advance and sorry for the yaml specific question but I am really struggling.

The html i am using is

```
                <form:form class="ym-form" name="shortsAndOversForm" commandName="shortsAndOversForm" method="post">                                    
                    <div class="ym-fbox" id="weekEndingDateDiv">
                      <form:label path="weekEndingDate"><spring:message code="label.weekEndingDate"/><sup class="ym-required">*</sup></form:label>
                      <form:input path="weekEndingDate" class="{required:true}" placeholder="enter a value"/>
                    </div>  
                    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="ym-button ym-primary" value="<spring:message code="button.runReport"/>" title="<spring:message code="button.runReport" />" />                        
                </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone else the answer to this question is to change the display:block property to display:inline inside the ym-form input css classes.